# Unity won't open shader file in shader graph editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to the shader in unity, I have downloaded some assets from the unity assets store that include some shader files, but when I try to edit, it opens as a code editor, not a shader graph editor. how to solve this?

currently, I'm using unity 2020.3.0f1 and shader graph already installed as I'm using URP.

Comment: Shaders are always text files. The shader graph editor can only open - you guessed it - .shadergraph files. They are used to generate shader code (= text) which is then compiled.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a way to solve this, but when you create an `Unlit Shader` the extension of the file would be `.shader`, this is a code file so it will always open with the editor, you need to keep in mind that in order for you to open a file with the Shader Graph editor the file needs to have the `.shadergraph` extension, so after you install the Shader Graph from the Package manager just create a new Shader and select `Sub Graph` this should create a `.shadersubgraph` file that you can open with the Shader Graph editor.